# Difference between write_unlock/write_unlock_irqrestore/write_unlock_irq/write_unlock_bh?

Tags: c, linux-kernel

In Linux kernel we have multiple read-write lock methods:

```
void write_unlock(rwlock_t *lock);
void write_unlock_irqrestore(rwlock_t *lock, unsigned long flags);
void write_unlock_irq(rwlock_t *lock);
void write_unlock_bh(rwlock_t *lock);
```

Does anyone know the difference and possible scenario?

Comment: Taking the question literally: `write_unlock` should "close" the critical section started with `write_unlock`, `write_unlock_irqrestore` - with `write_lock_irqsave`, `write_unlock_irq` - with `write_lock_irq` and `write_unlock_bh` - with `write_lock_bh`. If you want to know about suffixes `_irqsave`, `_irq` and `_bh`, I would suggest to google for functions in `spin_lock` family (`spin_lock_irqsave`, `spin_lock_irq`, `spin_lock_bh`): normal spinlocks are used much more and SO has much more questions than for rw-locks.

Comment: There is a [table of minimum locking requirements](https://www.kernel.org/doc/htmldocs/kernel-locking/cheatsheet.html) between various contexts. The table is given for spin-locks, but also applies to read-write locks.

Answer (score 0):

```
write_unlock()               Releases given lock

write_unlock_irq()           Releases given lock and enables local interrupts

write_unlock_irqrestore()    Releases given lock and restores local interrupts to given previous state
 
write_unlock_bh()              Releases given lock, and enables local interrupts (bottom half)
```